# how to display or hide the node button | node-red

Tags: node-red

is it possible to show or hide the button from a node in nodered?

I would like to show or hide the node button depending on the node configuration.

In the "oneditprepare" function i dosn't access to the button configuration.

Comment: Which button do you mean? Like the one on the end of the inject/debug node or one in the Config space?

Comment: I mean the button, which for example appears to the left of the Inject Node.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can add/remove a button based on the configuration of the node. The node either has a button or it does not depending on the `button` property in the object passed to `RED.nodes.registerType()` in the node's html file.